How do I fix this Underwriters Laboratories light fixture part that's missing side clips?
One of my light fixtures (recessed ceiling) fell in the kitchen. It's a UL thing that stays in place with these metal clips that go in the holes you can see in the images below. What happened to the clips, who can say. Must have broken apart or something.
As you can imagine I would rather fix this one lamp than replace all the 10 lamps... But I can't seem to find anything about it online.
I considered "borrowing" some clips from other lights but some of them are already missing and it doesn't feel like a practical solution.
Thanks in advance for any tips!



some of them are already missing, does not sound like good quality or have a long lifetime anyway.

Well, I'm sure they've been in there for a while. Not entirely sure of when the kitchen was "done" last time.

BTW - UL is a safety certification organization not the manufacturer of the light

Check the rest of the labeling for the manufacturer's name and the model number of the fixture.  Realistically, you might be looking for a new fixture as parts can be hard to track down. Might use a good flashlight and a mirror to look for them on the upper side of the ceiling drywall, through the holes the fixtures were in. Then go after them with a magnet.

https://ul.org/

Thanks for the help, everyone!
I looked in there with a flashlight and found one clip. It's not much but is doing the job right now.
And yes, UL is just the certification -- the extra information was in the can with the lamp itself.

This is a DIY site -- it would be trivial to cut duplicate clips from sheet metal, or even a heavy-weight can, and but a minute to form it into a similar shape. Beauty is not  factor; the clips are hidden and need only hold the fixture in place. Use pop-rivets and washers, or locking nuts and bolts, to mount them.
